# Value is POSTED definitely but isset() says NO

Tags: php, isset

See the code give given below. I was fighting with this code since last 5 hours to know why isset() is evaluating the condition as false if value is posted exactly what it shall POST.
If I uncomment the line no. - 4,5,6,7,8 and put rest of the code from line no. 10 to 28 I can see the POSTED value .
Can Anyone help in this by any guidance or suggestion. I will be thankful.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
include 'functions.php';

// var_dump($_POST); what happens when you uncomment this line?

//sec_session_start();
 //  $email = $_POST['logemail'];
 //  $password = $_POST['p'];
//  echo $password;
//  echo $email;
 // Our custom secure way of starting a php session. 

if(isset($_POST['logemail'], $_POST['p'])) { 
   $email = $_POST['logemail'];
   $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
   if(login($email, $password, $mysqli) === true) {
      // Login success
      //$url = 'mwq';
    //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  
    echo $password;
    echo $email;

   } else {
      // Login failed
      header('Location: login.php?error=1');
   }
} else { 
   // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
   echo 'Invalid Request Data Not POSTED';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share with us the HTML code, specially the form code.

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` and make absolutely sure those two indices are being set (even if you're sure that the submitting page should be working correctly).

Comment: A var_dump of _POST shows the values as set?  That var_dump is  followed *immediately* by `isset` check that returns false?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` Are you sure they are both set - you will set output from 4-8 even if only one is set.

Comment: I already tested with var_dump($_POST); and unfortunately I got this output - array(0) { } But WHY??

Comment: Well there is your problem...

Comment: i edited your post to make sure you're var_dumping in the right place. Is this correct and you get an empty value? Are you positive you're re-posting the form as you test? I will remove my edit after knowing if you are checking in the right spot and not inside your isset check

Comment: array(0) { } out from echo var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Array ( [error] => 1 ) outout from print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: Does your form include the method="post" attribute? May be a silly question, but I can't see the HTML and $_POST is apaprently empty.

Comment: Try using firebug or chrome dev tools to see what is being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the form I can only theorize what happens:

1. You started with a clean slate, the form shows, you enter the username and password and submit it
2. The code passes the condition and then performs the login
3. The result of `login(...) !== true` for whatever reason (wrong password or bug in the code)
4. The page redirects to `login.php?error=1`.

Now, the `$_POST` is empty and `$_REQUEST` contains `array('error' => 1)`. Perhaps the `login.php` shouldn't redirect to itself but rather redirect back to the page where you show the form.